# DropDownList select lowest value greater than X

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a DropDownList control and I want to set the SelectedValue to the lowest value in the dropdownlist greater than 0

for example my control drpExample has the following values:

```
0
0.90
2
3.32
```

I want to use drpExample.SelectedValue = The lowest value greater than 0

The SelectedValue should then be 0.90

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: yes, 0.9 is greater than 0. This drop down returns shipping rates. I want it to be defaulted to the lowest cost shipping, but I don't want to select 0 which is for collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim lowestItem As Decimal = 0
For Each item As ListItem In ddl.Items
    Dim itemValue As Decimal = CDec(item.Value)
    If itemValue > 0 AndAlso (lowestItem = 0 Or itemValue < lowestItem) Then lowestItem = itemValue
Next
ddl.SelectedValue = lowestItem
```

Where `ddl` is your DropDownList control ID.

Comment: Hi Curt, Doesn't seem to do anything for me at all. Nothing new is selected.

Comment: I've made a slight edit, you can try that. Have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: This isnt working for me either sorry. Debug: 'drpDelivery' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value

Comment: @Will Try my new edit. This one works (tested). This issue was because the object type was integer and not decimal.

Answer (score 2):

Or try this:

```
Dim L As New List(Of Decimal)
For Each item As ListItem In DropDownList.Items
    L.Add(CDec(item.Value))
Next
ddl.selectedvalue = L.Min()
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do it like this:

```
    For Each i As ListItem In DropDownList1.Items
        If i.Value > 0 And i.Value < DropDownList1.SelectedValue Then
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = i.Value
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Hi Zishan, This seems to behaving a bit odd. A new value is selected but it seems to be selecting items higher than the lowest values greater than 0 :(

Comment: Hi Will. To get a lower value, replace the ">" with "<". That should work.

Comment: This won't work. It'll just select the first value which is greater than 0.

Comment: It wont even do that sorry, Thanks Zishan though for your efforts.